# TSQL - What Did I Update Here?

Tags: sql-server

```
update outbound.notification
set statuscode = 1
select * from outbound.Notification
where statuscode = 4 --not in (3,6) 
and convert(varchar,createdtimestamp,102) > '2015.01.10'
and OutboundID <> 647
```

Executed the above query. Meant to have the select commented out, so that I could alternate between selecting queries in that status and updating them. What did I do to what rows?

Comment: You can issue rollback to undo the updates witin the same session if you use BEGIN TRANSACTION before you run your transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You updated all rows of `outbound.Notification`. Your query is generally two separate queries.

First, this updates all rows of `outbound.Notification`:

```
update outbound.notification set statuscode = 1
```

Second, this is just a `SELECT` statement.

```
select * from outbound.Notification
where statuscode = 4 --not in (3,6) 
and convert(varchar,createdtimestamp,102) > '2015.01.10'
and OutboundID <> 647
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought and feared. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Be careful next time.=)

Comment: Everyone did something like that at some point :D. Time to use your backups!